# C# compress short and long string

Tags: c#, compression

I want to manipulate one algorithm to compress both long and short strings in c#, all the algorithm that I had tried was able to compress long string but not short (about 5 characters). The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

namespace CompressString {
internal static class StringCompressor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compresses the string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <returns>compressed string</returns>
    public static string CompressString(string text)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);
        byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(gzBuffer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decompresses the string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="compressedText">The compressed text</param>
    /// <returns>uncompressed string</returns>
    public static string DecompressString(string compressedText)
    {
        byte[] gzBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(compressedText);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
            ms.Write(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }
}}
```

I got InvalidDataException (Found invalid data while decoding) in decompress method in the line:
zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
What are you suggest?

Comment: You should post some code as to what you have tried or at least expand on your question a bit. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Compression can *never* guarantee to make everything shorter... and compression of very small amounts of data is very rarely effective.

Comment: Example: if you have a string like `aaaaa` then you might be able to shorten it to something like `5a`. But if you have a string like `afgdc` then there is no really meaningful way to shorten it by algorithm. You could make a dictionary and say `1 = "afgdc"` and then submit only `1` but then the other side needs to know what `1` stands for so you need to also submit the dictionary and you haven't gained anything.

Comment: combine many short strings into 1 long somehow and then compress.

Comment: I have a string of maximum 1200 characters, to which limit I should not compress the string ?

Comment: To be honest, unless there is over 20% repetition of strings, there's no real benefit - especially in this day and age with strings of 1200 characters.

Comment: I wonder how many times this has been copy and pasted over the internet...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a special requirement that need to compress 5 characters ?
Otherwise you'll end up using CPU and memory for nothing: the chance to gain space on 5 characters are very low (4% to reduce to 4 characters, 0.1% to reduce to 3 characters, etc. and even less if the string can contains different case, punctuation, special characters etc.)

Comment: Yes, I have. So you are suggesting not to compress such short sting but from which length should I start compression if my string have a limit of 1200 characters?

Comment: Sorry I've no answer for you: you should test by yourself. Make a small code that produce random string of different length, then compress and compare the result. Do it 100s times for each length (i.e. 5, 10,20 etc) and write the result in a csv so you can open it in excel and make a graph. It should give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two fundamental issues. One is the error, one is the length.

The code you've shown seems to be the same as here:
http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/c-compress-and-decompress-strings-SID612.aspx

I can't attestify whether there are any bugs in this code, but it seemed to work fine for the random assortment of strings I tried on it (of varying lengths). Give us an example of a string that this code fails with and we can investigate further.

As for the length, the code is adding 4 bytes for the string length just to start with. So your odds of compressing a string of length 5 are zilch. That's not even mentioning the theoretical side. The pigeonhole principle is essentially based around the fact that there are more possible long strings than short strings. For example there are only 10 one digit numbers, but 100 two digit numbers. Therefore you can't shorten all 100 two digit numbers down to one digit. Also if you could compress any string, you could repeat the process and compress all strings down to one bit.

You could easily improve your compression a little two ways. If you know you won't be storing huge strings, you could cut down the stored string length, e.g. to 2 bytes instead of 4. And you could store a bit for whether you compressed the string or not, and store it uncompressed if the compressed version is bigger. It adds a 1 bit overhead for the compressed strings, but may be better if you want consistency.

Comment: For example, this code failed in compression the word 'headache'

Comment: actually I am very novice in compression algorithm so I will be very grateful for your help..

Comment: Hmm, same code worked for me with "headache". Can you show the code that you're calling this class with? The error might be there.

Can you explain any more about what you are trying to compress? Are they just words? Sentences? GZip is great, but not the solution to everything. For example, if we knew that there would only be letters and no numbers or punctuation, we could guaranteed compress it.